# RecyclerView Items have huge spaces between them

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that has several items. Rather than the items being directly under each other with the least possible amount of space between each row, there is a massive gap between each item like shown: (Sorry that the Image isn't very good, I took it on a small phone)

[Image displaying the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl6qk.png)

My layout file for the RecyclerView is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/layout_list_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/layout_list_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/layout_list_name"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layout_list_name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_list_name" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/layout_list_delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/layout_list_delete"
    android:src="@drawable/delete" />
```

How do I get rid of this massive gap?

Comment: Please see updated answer

Comment: post you xml containing recycle view

Comment: @jankigadhiya is it working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `layout_height="match_parent"` to `layout_height="wrap_content"`. That should hopefully solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of the parent layout to `wrap_content`. For the XML file you posted, it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```